# Mirror database between different Azure Accounts

Tags: sql-server, azure, database-mirroring, azure-data-sync

We have two different Azure Accounts with each having a set of databases.

Now, there is one database that we need to access in both the accounts with joins involving local tables (Especially one huge local table).

We tried distributed queries, but the performance dips with joins. We, therefore, want to mirror a table from the other azure account into this account's db so that it becomes a local table and join work faster.

We only need read only access to the mirrored table, the changes need to reflected almost instantaneously though the frequency of updates is not that high.

What is the way of achieving this ?

Comment: What do you mean by two different Azure accounts? Are you talking about different subscriptions or different enterprise accounts?

Comment: Two different enterprise accounts with different logins to Azure portal.

Comment: They are hosted in one region though if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using Azure SQL. Please mention that your DB is Azure SQL or on any VM using MS SQL. 
If it is Azure SQL, you can simply replicate your db with sync tool available in azure.
please follow this link:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync/

You can use single way sync so ops will get more faster.

HTH.

Comment: We are using Azure Databases. The issue is these databases are with two different AZURE accounts. 

I already looked at the azure data sync but there does not seem to be an option to select reference database in another azure account. It lists only the databases that have been added to the current account.

We do not want to download the client app as it means we need to maintain a  VM or server just for the sync app to sync between the two Azure DBs.